# Вывести каждое изображение в блоке через цикл

Tags: php

Необходимо вывести элементы `img` через цикл для отображения слайдера.

Делаю так:

```
<div id="projectPhotos" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">

    <?php
    $link = get_field('customer_website');
    $caption = $image['caption'];
     ?>
    <?php foreach ($images as $image) : ?>

     <div class="carousel-item active">
     <img class='img-fluid' src="<?php echo $image['url'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />

    <?php if ( !empty($link) ) : ?>
     <div class="project-gallery_popup-link">
     <a href="<?php echo $link ?>"><?php echo $image['caption'] ?></a>
 </div>
 <?php endif;?>
 </div>

  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Этот код выводит сразу все изображения в одном блоке (т.о. слайдер не работает).

Как вывести каждое отдельное изображение в блоке `carousel-item`?

Comment: а может все таки каждый в своем блоке просто у всех сразу класс `active` как из вашего кода видно `<div class="carousel-item active">`

Comment: да, каждое изображение должно быть в этом блоке. если убрать класс `active` ничего не изменится

Comment: да, ты прав. надо было проверку на `active` делать. спасибо!